# Internet blocked

Tags: blocked-services

Tor cannot connect and i cannot get internet access.
The internet is blocked on a time schedule. 
What can i do to fix the problem?

This is the log:

```
checking binary version: 0.2.8.9armx86-openssl1.0.2j
updating settings in Tor service
updating torrc custom configuration...
torrc.custom=ControlPortWriteToFile /data/data/org.torproject.android/app_bin/control.txt
SOCKSPort 9050
SafeSocks 0
TestSocks 0
WarnUnsafeSocks 1
TransPort 9040
DNSPort 5400
DNSListenAddress 0.0.0.0
VirtualAddrNetwork 10.192.0.0/10
AutomapHostsOnResolve 1
DisableNetwork 0
Log debug syslog
Log info syslog
SafeLogging 0
UseBridges 1
ClientTransportPlugin obfs3 exec /data/data/org.torproject.android/app_bin/obfs4proxy
ClientTransportPlugin obfs4 exec /data/data/org.torproject.android/app_bin/obfs4proxy
ClientTransportPlugin scramblesuit exec /data/data/org.torproject.android/app_bin/obfs4proxy
Bridge obfs4 154.35.22.10:1984 8FB9F4319E89E5C6223052AA525A192AFBC85D55 cert=GGGS1TX4R81m3r0HBl79wKy1OtPPNR2CZUIrHjkRg65Vc2VR8fOyo64f9kmT1UAFG7j0HQ iat-mode=0 
Bridge obfs4 154.35.22.12:1984 00DC6C4FA49A65BD1472993CF6730D54F11E0DBB cert=N86E9hKXXXVz6G7w2z8wFfhIDztDAzZ/3poxVePHEYjbKDWzjkRDccFMAnhK75fc65pYSg iat-mode=0 
GeoIPFile /data/data/org.torproject.android/app_bin/geoip
GeoIPv6File /data/data/org.torproject.android/app_bin/geoip6
ExitNodes {US}
StrictNodes 0


success.
Waiting for control port...
Control Port config file does not yet exist (waiting for tor): /data/data/org.torproject.android/app_bin/control.txt
Unable to start Tor: java.io.IOException: Unable to add commands to a closed shell
java.io.IOException: Unable to add commands to a closed shell
    at org.sufficientlysecure.rootcommands.Shell.add(Shell.java:318)
    at org.torproject.android.service.TorService.exec(TorService.java:1009)
    at org.torproject.android.service.TorService.runTorShellCmd(TorService.java:970)
    at org.torproject.android.service.TorService.startTor(TorService.java:799)
    at org.torproject.android.service.TorService.access$200(TorService.java:77)
    at org.torproject.android.service.TorService$IncomingIntentRouter.run(TorService.java:352)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Set background service to FOREGROUND
TorService is shutting down
Orbot is deactivated
Reading control port config file: /data/data/org.torproject.android/app_bin/control.txt
Set background service to FOREGROUND
Orbot is starting…
Orbot is starting…
updating settings in Tor service
updating torrc custom configuration...
torrc.custom=ControlPortWriteToFile /data/data/org.torproject.android/app_bin/control.txt
SOCKSPort 9050
SafeSocks 0
TestSocks 0
WarnUnsafeSocks 1
TransPort 9040
DNSPort 5400
DNSListenAddress 0.0.0.0
VirtualAddrNetwork 10.192.0.0/10
AutomapHostsOnResolve 1
DisableNetwork 0
Log debug syslog
Log info syslog
SafeLogging 0
UseBridges 1
ClientTransportPlugin obfs3 exec /data/data/org.torproject.android/app_bin/obfs4proxy
ClientTransportPlugin obfs4 exec /data/data/org.torproject.android/app_bin/obfs4proxy
ClientTransportPlugin scramblesuit exec /data/data/org.torproject.android/app_bin/obfs4proxy
Bridge obfs4 154.35.22.10:1984 8FB9F4319E89E5C6223052AA525A192AFBC85D55 cert=GGGS1TX4R81m3r0HBl79wKy1OtPPNR2CZUIrHjkRg65Vc2VR8fOyo64f9kmT1UAFG7j0HQ iat-mode=0 
Bridge obfs4 154.35.22.12:1984 00DC6C4FA49A65BD1472993CF6730D54F11E0DBB cert=N86E9hKXXXVz6G7w2z8wFfhIDztDAzZ/3poxVePHEYjbKDWzjkRDccFMAnhK75fc65pYSg iat-mode=0 
GeoIPFile /data/data/org.torproject.android/app_bin/geoip
GeoIPv6File /data/data/org.torproject.android/app_bin/geoip6
ExitNodes {US}
StrictNodes 0


success.
Orbot is starting…
/data/data/org.torproject.android/app_bin/tor DataDirectory /data/data/org.torproject.android/app_data --defaults-torrc /data/data/org.torproject.android/app_bin/torrc -f /data/data/org.torproject.android/app_bin/torrc.custom
Reading control port config file: /data/data/org.torproject.android/app_bin/control.txt
Reading control port config file: /data/data/org.torproject.android/app_bin/control.txt
Waiting for control port...
Reading control port config file: /data/data/org.torproject.android/app_bin/control.txt
Connecting to control port: 48432
SUCCESS connected to Tor control port.
SUCCESS connected to Tor control port.
SUCCESS - authenticated to control port.
Starting Tor client… complete.
adding control port event handler
SUCCESS added control port event handler
Tor started; process id=28882
Starting polipo process
SUCCESS - authenticated to control port.
Starting Tor client… complete.
adding control port event handler
SUCCESS added control port event handler
found existing Tor process…
Polipo is running on port:8118
Polipo is running
Circuit (1) LAUNCHED: 
NOTICE: Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
orConnStatus ($8FB9F4319E89E5C6223052AA525A192AFBC85D55): LAUNCHED
Circuit (2) LAUNCHED: 
orConnStatus ($00DC6C4FA49A65BD1472993CF6730D54F11E0DBB): LAUNCHED
NOTICE: Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
WARN: Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.10:1984 ("Host unreachable") 
WARN: Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.12:1984 ("Host unreachable") 
Circuit (1) FAILED: ONEHOP_TUNNEL > S_INTERNAL > EED_CAPACITY
Circuit (2) FAILED: ONEHOP_TUNNEL > S_INTERNAL > EED_CAPACITY
```

Answer (score 1):

`WARN: Proxy Client: unable to connect to 154.35.22.10:1984 ("Host unreachable")`

It looks like there's a problem with your internet connection. That error normally means one of two things:

1. Your local system has no route to the host, meaning your internet connection is misconfigured or down.

*or*

2. A remote router is saying that address can't be routed to, meaning your ISP is misconfigured or blocking connections to that destination (normally I'd expect to see "Connection refused" in the case of censorship though).

Ensure that your internet connection is working properly. If it is then try using non-default obfs4 bridges from https://bridges.torproject.org/ or the builtin meek pluggable transports.